# Why Netlogon send dns query ipv6

Tags: active-directory

I use https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/mdm/policy-csp-admx-netlogon#admx-netlogon-netlogon-addresslookuponpingbehavior
set parametr addresslookuponpingbehavior to 2.
When I debug netlogon Nltest /DBFlag:2080FFFF I see in log

```
04/13 22:11:25 [MISC] [2036] NlQueryClientSiteFromAddressLookup: site lookup requested for CZC52220NH (CZC52220NH.domain.name) with lookup policy=0x2.
04/13 22:11:25 [MISC] [2036] NlQueryClientSiteViaDNS: querying IPV4=FALSE, IPV6=TRUE on CZC52220NH.domain.name.
04/13 22:11:25 [MISC] [2036] NlQueryClientSiteViaDNS: result: 0x251d from DnsQuery_W(DNS_TYPE_AAAA) on CZC52220NH.domain.name
04/13 22:11:25 [MISC] [2036] NlQueryClientSiteViaDNS: total of 0x0(0) DNS records found.
04/13 22:11:25 [MISC] [2036] NlQueryClientSiteViaDNS: returning 0x0.
04/13 22:11:25 [MISC] [2036] NlQueryClientSiteFromAddressLookup: result: 0x0 for CZC52220NH
04/13 22:11:25 [2036] RS: NO_CLIENT_SITE: CZC52220NH 11.0.3.243
```

Why ipv6 ? Help me set ipv4

Comment: The policy only apply to enterprise SKU or educational SKU for Windows 10/11. Please state the client OS version

Comment: Windows Server 2019 DomainController i create reg param addresslookuponpingbehavior in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Netlogon\Parameters

Comment: I'm trying to do:
the client has an ip address that is recorded in dns, and which is related to the site. But the client connects via vpn and DC sees it at a virtual ip address that does not belong to any site. Using addresslookuponpingbehavior, I just wanted the client to get to the site by DNS, and not by a virtual address